# PHP - want to check if user input has website address in it

Tags: php, web, input, hyperlink, textarea

I want that whenver a user inserts "www." in a comment textarea, the address from "www." until the first space will be a replaced with a link to that address:

```
"I love www.google.com"
turns into
"I love <a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a>"
```

Can you please tell me how to do this? (newbie)

(sorry for posting the earlier question I still don't quite get it).

Should I use `preg_match_all()`?

Comment: Yes that's it! Works good, thank you strubester and Ozzy. this place ROCKS!!!

Comment: Stackoverflow is a very helpful place i agree :D Something you may not know is when you post a question, if you find an answer you agree with most, you should click the Tick next to it so it marks the question as answered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
$text = preg_replace('/(www\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z\.]{2,})/', '<a href="http://\\1">\\1</a>', $text);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/www\.(*)\.com/',"<a href='www.$1.com'>www.$1.com</a>",$strUrl);
```

BAH beat me to the punch.

Comment: That assumes that it is just a .com domain :P and by using (*), your saying that anything can be a domain ^_^

Comment: -1 because only .com and we all know how that worked for email addresses (.co.uk email anyone?)